# create a variable and add to a data frame within a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

New to R, I am trying to rename/create a variable within a "for" loop, assign counter "i" to its name, and save it to a data frame. I cannot find a way to assign the counter to the name:

```
 df.final <- NULL
 for(i in 1:n) {
  print(i)
  v1[i] <- df$v1 ############## I need help with this
  df$v1[i] <- v1[i] ############## and this
  if(i==1){
     df.final <- df
  } else {
     df.final <- merge(df.final, df, by = "ID")
  }
 }
```

I found the following:

```
 tmpvar <- paste("v1", i, sep= "")
 assign(tmpvar, df$v1)
```

that helps with creating a loop-specific variable (first part), but then how do I add that variable to a data frame (second part)?

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: It would help if you post what you are starting with. What is in `df`? Maybe you can show us two steps of your desired process?

Comment: @vaettchen: Sorry for lack of clarity. Let's assume df is a cross-section dataset that contains an ID and v1. What I had to mention so that my question would make more sense is that I am reading in a dataset in each iteration and save its v1 to a new dataset called "df.final". By running this loop, I would like to get a new dataset "df.final" that contains: ID v1_1 v1_2  ... v1_n. Hope this is more clear. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the R community! It would help, if you could clarify your problem a little further with example code (input, desired output). I assume, that you're trying to create a new variable in every loop? Maybe the following helps:

Let's assume we'll do 3 iterations. I'll create a simple sample dataset with 2 columns

```
n <- 3
# create an example dataframe with 2 columns
df<- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,1),c(2,2),c(1,2)))
colnames(df)<- c("v1","ID")
```

Next, create an empty data.frame. In your last step, you cannot join by the column `ID` if `df.final` does not have a column with that name!

```
`df.final <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 0))
colnames(df.final)<- c("v1","ID")
```

Let's do the for loop

```
for(i in 1:n) {
  df[paste(colnames(df[1]),toString(i),sep ="_")] <- df[1] 
  if(i==n){
    df.final <- df
  } else {
    df.final <- merge(df.final, df, by = "ID") #there is no point of doing the join in my example!
  }
}
```

Since I am not sure, what exactly you wanted to do, I wrote some code, that copies the content of column 1 and writes it into a column that has the same name as column 1 plus a suffix of I. So let's look at the statement:

`colnames(df[1])` gives you back the name of the first column of the dataframe as a string (var1) 
`toString(i)` converts your iterator i to a string
By using the baste function with a `sep ="_"` you combine the name of the first column and your iterator to one string.

```
df["varname"]
```

is a way to refer to a column in a dataframe.

Your output will look like this

```
  v1 ID v1_1 v1_2 v1_3
1  1  1    1    1    1
2  2  2    2    2    2
3  1  2    1    1    1
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this codes will achieve you.  Another way of trick: when you create a intermediate dataframe, you rename the column name that equal to create column by using variable name.

```
for (i in 1:3){
  col_name <- paste0('add',i) 
  df_temp <- data.frame(add=runif(5))  #the new column you want to add
  colnames(df_temp) <- col_name       #change the column name 
  if (i==1){
    df_final <- df_temp
  }else{
    df_final <- cbind(df_final,df_temp)
  }
}

df_final
        add1      add2      add3
1 0.02338753 0.7503266 0.4517581
2 0.94139957 0.6460098 0.6369646
3 0.81601567 0.1825294 0.1289575
4 0.61678986 0.6715657 0.3979930
5 0.11424770 0.7712202 0.9129960
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you! Very helpful and educational for me.

Based on your answers, I am refining my question:

```
 n <- 5

 df.final <- NULL

 for(i in 1:n) {
 df<- as.data.frame(rbind(c(1,runif(1),100),c(2,runif(1),100),c(3,runif(1),100)))
   colnames(df)<- c("ID","v1","redundant")
   df[paste(colnames(df[2]),toString(i),sep ="_")] <- df[2] 
   df <- df[c("ID",colnames(df)[ncol(df)])] ### This works as I am referring to my new variable thorugh its column number but I still don't know how to identify the new variable, v1_i, through iterations? 
     if(i==1){
     df.final <- df
   } else {
     df.final <- merge(df.final, df, by = "ID")
   }
 }
```

I very recently switched to R from Stata and although I used to code in Matlab, it just takes time for me to adapt my mind to the new style of vector/matrix rather than variable/panel. Any improvement on this code is much appreciated! :)